# How fair is a direct comparison of clock frequencies of an ARM and and x86 processor?

Tags: performance, x86, arm, comparison

I was wondering, if I got an ARM processor (1GHz) and a x86 processor² (1GHz) and no other information about them, is it possible to give a general statement about which one of them would probably perform better in executing some arbitrary (complex) application.

I know the ARM (RISC) architecture was specifically developed to aid certain applications whereas the x86 architecture is just a compilation of legacy compatibility and workarounds (no bashing intended). Naturally, it would be important to know a little bit more about the application, i.e. which specific tasks (and thus instructions) might be executed most. Let's also put aside that there are different versions of those architectures.

Thus my question: Having those two unspecified processors with 1GHz clock frequency, is it possible to give an educated guess which one would perform better (i.e. will execute a general but complex application faster).

On a second note: If not possible (which is what I assume) what general parameters would be at least necessary to compare – except for comparing the assembly code of the application with the respective instruction sets of the architectures?

---

² to keep it simple, let's suppose they've got both a 32bit architecture and no specific AMD or Intel features.

Comment: Depends on specific CPU, really: http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/188396-the-final-isa-showdown-is-arm-x86-or-mips-intrinsically-more-power-efficient/2 , http://www.extremetech.com/computing/187862-nvidia-details-64-bit-denver-tegra-k1-claims-haswell-class-performance-for-first-64-bit-android-chip "x86" has been predominately targeted at non-mobile devices where power (and heat) and size are less of a concern. That is, an i7 will stomp any current ARM processor; but a low-power Atom offering can get beat with a Cortex A15.

Comment: That is, for the most part it is simply a trade-off between power consumption and performance within similar generation designs.

Comment: The premise is already highly flawed before you start trying to compare across architectures - just thinking about some ~10 year old laptops I have, can you say if the 2.2GHz x86 is "better" than the 1.4GHz x86 from the same era?

Comment: Seeing as the ARM parts are all used in battery powered devices, the more interesting question might be power-comsumotion for a particular operation frequently performed on those devices (8x8 DCT might be a good example as it's used heavily in video codecs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.  An x86 clocked that low might be a low-power design like Atom (esp. pre-Silvermont), or even-more-limited x86 design.  Modern desktop/laptop x86 CPUs can do a LOT per clock (about 4 instructions per clock, barring branch mispredicts, data dependencies, or execution port contention).  Google if you want IPC (insns per cycle) numbers for desktop CPUs on real code.

One CPU might be faster for some things, but slower for others, for tasks that stress different items on this list (that I just made up):

- Vector integer and/or FP math throughput
- unpredictable branches (data compression)
- workload size (cache)
- bandwidth to main memory
- bandwidth to cache
- large-code-footprint (instruction cache/fetch/branch-prediction buffer size)
- AES / CRC32C / SHA1 (supported by HW instructions in some CPUs).

### How to actually compare

Look at the `gcc` benchmark results from SPECint2000 or SPECint2006.  The other benchmarks that make up the whole SPECint suites are generally regarded as not as useful these days.  ([source - Realworldtech forum discussion](http://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=151036&curpostid=151122).  And yes, the "Linus" he's agreeing with is Linus Torvalds of Linux fame.)

> You can't game gcc, it has a fairly large cache footprint relative to
>   the others, stresses the branch predictor, etc. Since SPEC doesn't
>   include browser or GUI benchmarks, gcc is probably the closest you can
>   come to actually measuring smartphone performance.

Comment: Thx, I know it's not a trivial matter but I was still hoping that at least to some extend it's possible to make a prediction how they would perform. I'm going to accept your answer since because of the second part. ;)

Comment: The figure of metric that is instruction issue-rate.   Things are made more complex by x86 being a micro-coded architecture, and all modern parts translate the program-stream into core-instructions that are actually executed by the core.  Not surprisingly, the issue rates of each are different.

Comment: On current Intel designs, most of the common instructions decode to a single uop.  `cmp`, `test`, `add` and others can combine with `jcc` into a single uop.  You're correct that talking about 4 insns per cycle is a simplification.  It does depend on which instructions you run.

Comment: @artlessnoise:   I might have misunderstood your objection, but we're not talking about the code gcc generates.  It may well do better optimizing for an x86 target, but the question is how does gcc itself run, not how fast the resulting code is.  We're talking about the SPECint https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/403.gcc.html benchmark.  Are you claiming that gcc's parser and x86-target optimizer are written in ways that favour x86 hosts over other CPU architectures?  That RWT quote was EXACTLY this context: how to compare integer performance across CPU architectures.

Comment: Exactly;  gcc is tuned to compile faster on the x86. 90%+ of gcc developer use the x86.  There might be some PPC hosts which would be a little more like the ARM, but the amount of gcc developers using the ARM as a host will be near zero.  The best benchmark is an application you wish to use.  Linus uses gcc on the x86 a lot, a good benchmark for him.  Linus quote was not about different architectures.

Comment: @artlessnoise: you're right, that discussion was about benchmarks for comparing different flavours of ARM, including 32bit vs. AARCH64.  But not ARM vs. anything else.  Your suggestion sounds reasonable, that developers would have implemented things in ways that perform well on their own machines, when they did any performance-tuning at all.  I think most of the dev time spent on gcc is about getting it to generate faster code, vs. getting it to compile faster, but there has been some.  Still, do you have any sources for your suggestion that gcc is at an unfair disadvantage on non-x86?

Comment: I have to disagree with the part about people liking the SPECint gcc benchmark because they actually use a current version of gcc.  That's not what makes it a good benchmark.  They liked it because it has a larger code footprint, and in other ways is more like a web browser's code than any of the other SPECint benchmarks.

Comment: No, I have not source, but you are saying it is a good source of information.  Do you have a source on that?  I am pointing out that this might not be a reasonable test.  Generally, it is best to test something close to whatever your application might be (FFT, etc).  Often thing are memory bound and then the CPU is not as important as a bus interface.  For GCC this is the case and most embedded ARM systems will not do well as they may only have a 16bit memory interface.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the SPECint gcc benchmark might be a not-terrible proxy for performance of web-browser type things.  And no, I don't have a source either for my claims, other than that RWT discussion.  I was just asking.  Good point on benchmarking the thing you care about, if it's something other a web browser (which is one of the main apps everyone cares about for interactive use these days).  If JavaScript benchmarks are available, that's probably more useful than gcc, but SPECint numbers are available for more systems with better standardization.

Comment: So the main point is what you can do in *one clock* is highly variable and dependant on what you wish to accomplish.  If you compare a cell phone to a PC, the memory bandwidth will be much different.  So something like a web browers/javascript will be bad.  If the ARM CPU is synthesized for a tablet/laptop based design, then the memory BUS might be wider/better and comparable to a PC and hence my close vote; not a good question for SO.  An ARM can be found in **MANY** different types of designs.  Benchmark an embedded PC104 x86 board to a cell phone is closer (but still not the same).

Answer (score 5):

Following are comparisons from my 32 bit GCC benchmarks - Read more on my site::

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/

They represent percentage operations per CPU clock Hz for Android systems (Atom native Intel code), Raspberry Pi 2 A7 and Intel/AMD based PCs using Linux Ubuntu.

First is from Whetstone benchmark with tiny loops, where Intel and ARM can be quite similar.

Next is  Linpack benchmark with L2 cache speed dependency, where later technology shows improvements.

Finally, my maximum MFLOPS tests, with SSE instructions compiled for Intel and NEON for ARM, with Intel leaping ahead. Core i7 with AVX directive demonstrated up to 1147 MFLOPS per MHz.

Note results can depend on compiler release version.

```
                       Whetstone                 Linpack      Max
                        Float Functions  Integer    Float    Float

    Cortex-A9              22      1.7      124       17       95
    Cortex-A15             18      1.7      102       47      241
    Qualcomm 800           27      1.5      146       33
    Atom Z3745             30      1.7      182       22

    Cortex-A7              27      0.9      126       13       86

    Atom N455              19      0.7       63       12      110
    Athlon 64              28      1.6      113       42
    Phenom II              28      1.6      136       49      500
    Core 2 Duo             31      1.6      238       41      600
    Core i7 4820K          31      1.8      224       65      630
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, appreciate it. ;)

Comment: [Coremark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coremark) attempts to take the compiler out of the equation.  Although it is again a synthetic benchmark...

Answer (score 0):

No,not fair at all.  Like comparing any two random vehicles for any particular performance metric (top speed, lap time on some track, mileage, comfort, safety, etc), simply because they both have the same number of wheels.  Not really an interesting comparison to make predictions simply based on the number of wheels and brand names (not models) of the vehicles.